# Google script Utilities.formatDate not working?

Tags: google-apps-script

The day of week returned seems wrong sometimes. Today I executed in Google App Script engine:

```
Logger.log(Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "Europe/Madrid", "yyyy-MM-dd F"))
```

The result was:

```
[15-10-26 18:18:42:037 CET] 2015-10-26 4
```

The problem is the final **F which is translated to 4**, which corresponds to **Thursday**. However, today is Monday, right?

The worst thing is that if I add four days to this date, I get the correct one 5 which is "Friday"

```
[15-10-26 18:19:50:012 CET] 2015-10-30 5
```

What's wrong with this code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`"F"` is the [nth occurrence of the weekday in the month](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).
Today is the fourth Monday of the Month, Friday will be the fifth Friday of the month.

You probably want to use `"yyyy-MM-dd u"`